# Problems with assembling global stiffness matrix

Tags: finite-element-analysis

Can someone plese help me to find error in my code. Although the code compiles without any issues, the output is incorrect. So, firstly I calculated stiffnes matrices (Ke) for each element using for loop. Now I need to assemble it to global stiffnes matrix, but as the output it gives me zeros and only few values are nonzero. Nodes in "elements_surface_1" are represented as 621x3 array [[252 142 371], [279,188,280], [142,322,371]...[399,303,405]].Perhaps the problem is related to the loop. I suspect that the code only calculates Ke for the last element after running the code, so I added a print statement after the loop to check the value of Ke.
My code:

```
##Global stiffness matrix
nodes = np.delete(node_coords, 2, 1)
n_node=nodes.shape[0]
n_elem=elements_surface_1.shape[0]
K=np.zeros((n_node,n_node))
##For every element, compute element stiffness matrix Ke 
for i in range(n_elem):
  #for an element, which rows do I need to go read from the node_coords array?
  n1=elements_surface_1[i,0]
  n2=elements_surface_1[i,1]
  n3=elements_surface_1[i,2]
  x1=nodes[n1,0]
  y1=nodes[n1,1]
  x2=nodes[n2,0]
  y2=nodes[n2,1]
  x3=nodes[n3,0]
  y3=nodes[n3,1]
  Ae=Area(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
  k=1
  B=B_matrix(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) #B_matrix is function
  Ke=1/(4*Ae)*k*np.dot(np.transpose(B),B)

  print(Ke)


  ## ASSEMBLY
  K[n1,n1]+=Ke[0,0]
  K[n1,n2]+=Ke[0,1]
  K[n1,n3]+=Ke[0,2]

  K[n2,n1]+=Ke[1,0]
  K[n2,n2]+=Ke[1,1]
  K[n2,n3]+=Ke[1,2]
  
  K[n3,n1]+=Ke[2,0]
  K[n3,n2]+=Ke[2,1]
  K[n3,n3]+=Ke[2,2]
```

solutions how to solve the problem